# How can execute two functions respectively in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have used the code prepared in https://www.pythoncircle.com/ to import and export an excel file using Django. 
This code is provided below:

```
from Django.shortcuts import render
import openpyxl

views.py file:
def index(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

        worksheet = wb["Sheet1"]
        print(worksheet)

        excel_data = list()
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
            row_data = list()
            for cell in row:
                row_data.append(str(cell.value))
            excel_data.append(row_data)

        return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {"excel_data":excel_data})

import xlwt
from django.http import HttpResponse


def download_excel_data(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="ThePythonDjango.xls"'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet("sheet1")
    row_num = 0

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True


    columns = ['Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', ]
    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()


    wb.save(response)
    return response

urls.py file:
from django.urls import path
from django.http import HttpResponse

from . import views

app_name = "myapp"


urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', views.download_excel_data, name='download_excel_data'),
```

]

When I run the described code, only the index function is executed. while when I change the urlpatterns to:
    urlpatterns = [

```
    path('', views.download_excel_data, name='download_excel_data'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),    
]
```

the download_excel_data function is executed.
How can I execute both functions respectively?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When DJANGO searches URLS.py it is searching for the first match. When it finds a match, the search is over and it serves up the function called for in the URL. You can actually use the behaviour to your advantage when using Frontend applications such a Vue or React.

So when you have index first DJANGO matches the URL with index and excutes the index view. When you changed them around with download_excel_data first it gets matched first therefore it executes.

If you want them both to execute together probably simplest is to combine them into one view.

Stylistically, python imports normally sit at the top of the file for all the functions below. It just seems weird seeing import statements in between functions. There is a whole heap of conventions for python covered in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you're interested.

Summary: Combine them under one view.